# Average Game Length (Gambler's Ruin)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, gambling

Two players, A and B, start a game with i and N-i chips, respectively. The game consists of repeatedly flipping a fair coin with A receiving 1 chip from B if heads turns up and B receiving 1 from A otherwise. The game ends as soon as one of the two players runs out of chips. If this game is played many times, what is the average duration (length) E(N,i) of a game? Compute an explicit formula for E(N,i) and provide a detailed derivation.

The average length of the game will depend on the total number of chips and on how many chips each player has, hence the indicated dependence on (N,i).

Answer (score 3):

A start: Since $N$ is fixed, it is not particularly useful to mention it. Let $a_i=E(N,i)$. For most $i$, we have the recurrence
$$a_{i}=1+\frac{1}{2}(a_{i-1}+a_{i+1}).$$
But for example $a_1=1+\frac{1}{2}a_2$.